# How to remove percentage symbol while extracting records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table employee:

```
Name Percentage
---------------
rad    80%
deepak 20%
kavita 30%
```

I want to write a SQL select query using SQL Server 2008 to returns these results:

```
rad 80
deepak 20
kavita 30
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What **datatype** is your column `Percentage` in the database table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To Replace single Character in select query:** 
You can simply use the Replace Function whenever you want to strip any character here is how the general syntax will look like

```
REPLACE ( StringExpression, StringPattern, ReplacementString)
```

so in your case its gonna be something as follows

```
SELECT name, REPLACE(percentage,'%','');
GO
```

Note that you can also use another method for same purpose i.e. COLLATE Function

```
SELECT REPLACE('percentage'  COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,'%', '');
GO
```

If you want to know More About Using COLLATE, take a look at this [LINK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx)

Hope my answer will help you to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you need, Replace will not work
SELECT REPLACE('rad 80% deepak 20% kavita 30%','%','');

**Edit**

```
Select name, REPLACE(percentage,'%','');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also use AS to redefine the name of the column. When you use REPLACE, the column changes its name to the position number. So the correct code to maintain the column title would be:

```
SELECT name, REPLACE(percentage,'%','') AS PERCENTAGE FROM TABLENAME;
```

I'm a bit late, but hope this helps people with this issue now :)